# Using OS 9 resource fork fonts in CSS with @font-face

Tags: html, css, macos, fonts, font-face

I have some old OS 9 fonts which contain the font data in the resource fork. When I try to link such a font in a @font-face and open up the HTML in a browser, the text still appears in the default font.

On searching around, I found that the font data can be copied to a regular ttf file using the rsrc attribute. So I ran the command `cp <font>/rsrc <font>-attr.ttf` and tried linking the new file in the @font-face. Again, the text showed up in the default font.

Another discussion on stackoverflow suggested binary printing and copying of the data using `xattr -p <font> | xxd -r > <font>-xxd.ttx`. Once again, linking this file failed to change the font.

Just to make sure that the HTML was correct, I linked a newer ttf font from the same directory and it worked correctly. Does anyone know if the old fonts can be used in @font-face, with or without any conversion. Thank you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Font Suitcases can potentially hold 2 different kinds of fonts: bitmap fonts and TrueType fonts. Bitmap fonts would be `'NFNT'` resources along with the necessary `'FOND'` (font family information). On the other hand, TrueType fonts would be `'sfnt'` resource entries along with the necessary `'FOND'` (font family information). Normally, font suitcases that hold bitmap font data are only one half of the font; to be usable you need to have the additional PostScript Outline font files (these will have an `LWFN` icon).

Otherwise, the font suitcase can represent a TrueType font, which compared to a "PostScript Type 1 Font Suitcase", is truly self-contained.

To convert from a resource-file-based Mac TrueType font to a Windows TrueType font, you just need to extract the `'sfnt'` resource entries).

Since Rosetta is no more, I'm without Resorcerer, so I've managed to whip up a barebones resource file editor.

https://markdouma.com/developer/ResourceFinagler.zip

I just added a few lines so that you can now select the individual `'sfnt'` resources like shown in the image below, and drag them to the Finder to create the individual Windows TrueType fonts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I wish I could give you some sort of extra props for this software.

Comment: my font suitcase has the bitmap fonts inside - are the steps still the same? I can't seem to select any of the nested files to drag out.

Comment: @GhostEcho: sorry, didn't notice this comment till just now. I only made `'sfnt'` resources draggable, since they correspond to the data contained in a .ttf file. `'NFNT'` resources are bitmap fonts and aren't really usable in OS X: if the font suitcase contains no `'sfnt'` resources, it may be a PostScript Type 1 font that stores the outline font data in separate files (in `'POST'` resources). You'd first need to convert those fonts to a Mac TrueType font (or straight to a Windows TrueType font) using other software before they'd be usable.

Comment: Excellent program. The only problem is - i need convert **many** resource-fork based fonts. The command line variant would be nice - e.g. something what i can run from the Terminal like: `sfnt2ttf /path/to/file -o new.ttf` or like...

Comment: I don't know why, but dragging for me not working :( Mac Sierra (10.12.2 (16C67))

Comment: I modified a font in 1997 and only had the .suit file, needed to use it on the web and in an SVG across Windows and OS X. Your software enabled me to extract the .ttf after all those years, so thanks!

Comment: Thank you, @NSGod, your tool proved super useful.

Comment: @NSGod Amazing you created this, just for this purpose! Excellent! Still works perfectly in 2018 Mojave 10.14.1

Answer (score 3):

Since this is one of the first search results when searching how to handle Resource fork fonts on modern macOS systems here is a solution for batch converting a large group of font suitcases.

First we can group them all in a single directory taking advantage of the find command, because find doesn't see the resource fork and consider the file empty, we create a new directory in the user home and copy all the suitcases there:

```
mkdir ~/rsrc
find . -type f -empty -exec cp {} ~/rsrc/ \;
```

Then in mac we can use [brew](https://brew.sh/) to install Fondu

```
brew install fondu
```

Finally we move to the directory with all the suitcases and run fondu on each file like this, the secret to get fondu to work is to make it read the resource fork by adding /../namedfork/rsrc at the end of the file, otherwise it fails.

```
cd ~/rsrc
find . -type f -empty -exec fondu -force {}/..namedfork/rsrc \;
```

When the command finishes you should have a folder with the new .ttf, .bdf and .pfb files.

You can delete the suitcase files from this directory running:

```
find . -type f -empty -delete
```

Comment: How did you install `fondu`? Brew reports no formulae of that name

Answer (score 0):

The font data in an old Mac OS font suitcase is not in TTF format -- copying the resource fork to a TTF file will give you Mac OS resource data in a file named "font.ttf", which isn't right. You'll need to use a tool like FontForge (free/open-source) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Apple Silicon Macs and is based on Diego Alifano's answer above.

Copy your resource fork files to some better location.

```
find . -type f -empty -exec cp {} ~/YOUR/FOLDER/HERE/ \;
```

You cannot install Fondu using `brew` anymore. Instead download its tar ball source from Fondu's website: https://fondu.sourceforge.net/index.html#Downloads. Extract it.

This source code also no longer compiles without modifications because of dynamic system libraries are no longer located on the file system; `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices` does not exist in macOS Ventura 13.5. Once you have it open, alter the file called `Makefile.in`. Remove the line:

```
DARWIN_CORE = $(if $(findstring apple-darwin,$(HOST)),/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices,)
```

Then execute in terminal in the directory in which the Fondu source was put: `./configure; make`. Fondu is small and it should compile rapidly. I am not sure whether this old (seemingly unmaintained) code base will continue working; I therefore don't bother with `make install`.

In the location where your font files are:

```
find . -type f -empty -exec /PATH/TO/YOUR/MADE/fondu -force {}/..namedfork/rsrc \;
```

If you `make install`'ed it, you won't need to provide the path to the made `fondu`. And to clean up the now redundant old-style resource forks: `find . -type f -empty -delete`.