# Custom Font for label

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel

I'm trying to use a custom font for a label in iOS.
The font I'm trying to use is System Font "Cooper Black". I can't actually find a file extension for it. I have added the font to the plist and to my project but can't get it working. 
Does anyone know the actual name of Cooper Black? and how to refer to it in the plist and code.
Here's my code

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Cooper Black" size:14]];
```

Comment: Call `familyNames` and `fontNamesForFamilyName:` to find your font's name. It is presumably a `.ttf`.

Comment: And Please Ensure about `Font File Name` and the `Font Name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the font name by looking for the app in the Font Book app on your Mac: [image: Font Book App Screen Shot]

Search for the Font and select it, then click on the info tab to get the name to use the font.  Also, you can find the available fonts using fontNamesForFamilyName like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Arial"]);
```

will print:

```
    (
        ArialMT,
        "Arial-BoldItalicMT",
        "Arial-ItalicMT",
        "Arial-BoldMT"
    )
```

Then set it like so:

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldItalicMT" size:20]];
```

Comment: I have tried it with CooperBlackMS but it still doesn't work. The file I added to the project from Font Book is called Cooper Black, but in Finder its type is "Font Suitcase" Not sure what that is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the fonts have to be ttf or otf format to work with iOS.  You can convert it from Font Suitcase, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412462/using-os-9-resource-fork-fonts-in-css-with-font-face/7418915#7418915

Comment: If you use the app that is in the question that I linked, you will be able to pull out "Cooper Black.ttf".  The font name is then "CooperBlack"  I just tried it myself, got the ttf and put into a project to test it.

Comment: Thanks for linking that program, just have no idea how to use it. Could you post a quick guide how you got the Cooper Black.ttf out?

Comment: Don't worry, I got it! Right click on the font suitcase and open it with the app, then drag out the font you wish to extract. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add in storyboard a Label. Associate it with your font family.
Then:

```
let name = mylabel.font.description
print("font name \(name)")
```

> font name  font-family:
>   "**WeatherIcons-Regular**"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;
>   font-size: 17.00pt

**WeatherIcons-Regular** is your font family you need.