# How can I access a .suit font file in Lua/MacOS with io.open? .ttf/.otf works fine, suit doesn't

Tags: macos, file, lua, macos-high-sierra

I am converting a .ttf/.otf font file reader in Lua 5.2 from Windows to MacOS and also want to add support for .suit font files which include ttf fonts.

Plain .ttf/.otf files now work fine, but already the reading of a .suit file doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to read the bytes of the .suit font on MacOS?
Does it have to do with a file name alias?

```
local input = assert(io.open("/Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf", "rb"))
local data=input:read("*all")
print(string.byte(data,1)) --prints the correct value 0
io.close(input)

local input = assert(io.open("/Library/Fonts/Maestro.suit", "rb"))
local data=input:read("*all")
print(string.byte(data,1))  --prints nothing
io.close(input)
```

The upper part (Tahoma) prints the correct first byte value 0, while the bottom part prints nothing, although I would have expected the value 0.

When I use string.len(data), it shows the correct value for Tahoma, but 0 for Maestro, although it should be something like 46k.

Comment: Is `.suit` file actually a folder, not a regular file?

Comment: It's not a folder though it can bundle several font files. I have only found this information: MacOS stores fonts in "resources" ( https://fontforge.github.io/macformats.html ), but this doesn't explain why I can open a .ttf, but not a .suit file. I have also found this tool ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412462/using-os-9-resource-fork-fonts-in-css-with-font-face ) that can extract a .ttf from a .suit, but I am looking for a more direct solution to load the bytes of the .suit file.

Comment: Probably, "resource fork" is something similar to an additional file stream on Windows.  `io.open` reads only "main" fork/stream.  For example, the "resource fork" would be lost if file is copied from Mac-compatible partition to ext4.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But I can't believe that is not possible to load the file in Lua. The .suit file can be copied and sent per mail, just like any other normal file. Then why should it not be possible to load it byte by byte. I have also tried renaming it (changed suit to ttf), same result.

Comment: `The .suit file can be copied and sent per mail, just like any other normal file.`  Try to copy it on USB disk **formatted as FAT32**, and then check if "resource fork" remained of vanished.

Comment: Same result on a USB disk with FAT16 (I assume there is no difference on FAT32): .ttf can be opened, .suit can't.

Comment: Do you have some standard app that can open or list content of .suit file?  Does it open .suit on both HDD and USB?

Comment: The answer below worked for me:


See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8455 .suit is not a folder, but it can be addressed like a folder. To open the font part in the .suit file use:

    local file=io.open("/Library/Fonts/Maestro.suit/..namedfork/rsrc","rb")

Comment: If something looks like a folder and is accessed like a folder... :-)

Answer (score 0):

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8455 .suit is not a folder, but it can be addressed like a folder. To open the font part in the .suit file use:

local file=io.open("/Library/Fonts/Maestro.suit/..namedfork/rsrc","rb")